# UWP Combobox SelectedItem ignores its bound value

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

To illustrate both success and failures, I'm going to use the following backend. In each case, I have an array of things, and a Property that is set to the array.First().

```
public class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        FirstString = Strings.First();
        FirstItem = Items.First();
    }

    public string FirstString { get; set; }
    public Item FirstItem { get; set; }

    public string[] Strings => new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    public Item[] Items => new[]
    {
        new Item {Index = 1},
        new Item {Index = 2},
        new Item {Index = 3},
        new Item {Index = 4}
    };
}

public class Item
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

So here is a binding results in the item in the `SelectedItem` being selected

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Strings}" 
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind FirstString}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="system:String">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

And here is the identical code for the alternate items that fails to select

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" 
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind FirstItem}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Index}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Additionally as soon as I turn on `Mode=TwoWay` this clears my value in the VM during the initial bind.

So my question is, Why? What is different to cause this?

Comment: What does your output window say?

Comment: very interesting question you got here. I'll use it in my interviews going forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting problem. Here's what's going on.

Essentially what you are doing is you are returning a new collection of Items every time rather than caching it. Since your Items getter gets called twice, once from the ItemsSource Binding, and once from the FirstItem binding, the collection is instantiated twice.

Because Item is a reference type, the two instances of Item {Index = 1} are not equal so they don't match and the Selected Item binding does not work. It works for strings because those are value types and "1" still equals "1" even though they are different instances.

To solve it, you need to cache return the same instance of Items every time its getter is called:

```
public MainPage()
{
    ...
    Items = new Item[] {...};
    ...
    FirstItem = Items.First();
}

public Item[] Items {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Unfortunately this is the distilled down version of the problem I'm having, and so far this hasn't fixed the problem in my app. (Follow up question soon:-) )